# AngularJs ng-repeat with long index (integer) throws error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have two objects with the same date but with id . (double) :

```
{
  id: 1541672305932,
  date: 2018-01-01 11:11:11
}
{
  id : 1541672305933,
  date: 2018-01-01 11:11:11
}
```

and I got a duplicate error if the date is exactly the same
but if the id is simple id like . 1,2 its working I guess is the length of the id

how can I fix it ,, i have to use the id as the index 
my ng repeat looks like

```
 <li id="item_{{event.id}}" ng-repeat="event in list track by event.id">
```

error i got

```
Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: event in historyList track by event.id, Duplicate key: 1541672305932, Duplicate value: 

{"date":"2018-11-08T10:18:25.000Z",id":1541672305932}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WYwbrv?editors=1010

Comment: there shouldn't be any duplicates, no matter the length. Can you double check the code you are posting

Comment: yes  i use timestamp with miliseconds and  for sure of i chnaged the id its will be fine 
but part of the number is the same. maybe angular not supporting long id ?

Comment: The MAX_SAFE_INTEGER is 9,007,199,254,740,991 but your example is less than that. For more information, see [MDN `Number.isSafeInteger()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isSafeInteger)

Comment: after `Math.pow(2, 53)`, their difference will not be counted, so you will have duplicates. Once again, double check your code, it should work

Comment: @Tuz it works fine: https://codepen.io/karlen/pen/mQPdmx?editors=1010

Comment: @KarlenKishmiryan i updated the example , its not working .. 1541672305932

Comment: @Tuz in your updated example, you are indeed using the same id.

Comment: https://tppr.me/CBWLj

Answer (score 0):

You can try track by  `track by  $index` instated of track by `event.id`

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    
    $scope.list =[
  {
    "id": '1234567894567',
    "date": "2014-03-13T05:53:12 -06:-30"
  },
  {
    "id": '123456789789',
    "date": "2014-12-15T01:32:39 -06:-30"
  },
  {
    "id": '123456789789',
    "date": "2014-12-15T01:32:39 -06:-30"
  }
]

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">


<li id="item_{{event.id}}" ng-repeat="event in list track by  $index">{{event.id}}</li>

</div>
```